# Converting Degrees, Mintues, Seconds to X, Y to be plotted into ponts

Tags: latitude-longitude

I need to convert a longs list of Lat/Long (example: N42 30' 45" W122 38' 00") into X,Y data (42.5125, -122.633333) so I can plot it into point shapefile.
Is there a a way to convert multiple records at once from an excel spreadsheet? Maybe an excel formula that I can plug in or a online tool?

Comment: Where have you looked? Have you tried splitting it into three new columns in Excel and then doing the arithmetic on those columns to get decimal degrees?

Comment: It worked! Thanks for the advice. Just divvied the Min by 60 and the Sec by 3600 and concatenated everything.

Comment: Your title and question body ask different questions. And your example has a Y that is 32.6 degrees south of the South Pole. Seconds are 3600th of a degreee, and minutes are sixtieths of a degree. Be sure to apply the negation from S and W after doing the math.

Comment: Vince, do you mean that ArcMap treats "X" as Long and "Y" as Lat? and not the other way around? Because when I go into ArcMap and use the "Display X/Y Data" and follow the ArcMap prompt the XY the points show up in the correct position.